Develop Dynamic Web Project using Eclipse EE and a custom Tomcat+Axis2 server on Docker
I'm trying to set up a new Dynamic Web Project using Eclipse EE.
I have my working copy of Tomcat+Axis2 server on a Docker container.
I used a Dockerfile to build the image (axis2.war is in the same directory)
FROM tomcat:9.0.88-jdk11

RUN mkdir -p /usr/local/tomcat/webapps
COPY axis2.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/axis2.war

and docker compose to start the container
services:
  tomcat:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: tomcat-axis2
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8443:8443"
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536

so the server is running fine and Axis works correctly.
When IDE asks for a local copy of Tomcat is where I'm stuck at. Is there a way to mount /usr/local/tomcat on the container to my machine and point eclipse to that mountpoint? Or is there any alternative?
I already tried to add this to the docker-compose.yml
services:
  tomcat:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: tomcat-axis2
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      - "8443:8443"
    environment:
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx1024m
    ulimits:
      nofile:
        soft: 65536
        hard: 65536
  volume:
    - type: bind
      source: ./tomcat
      target: /usr/local/tomcat

resulting in the overwriting of the target folder with my newly created empty folder and Tomcat not working anymore.

In the setup you've shown, you don't have a local Tomcat your IDE will be able to see.  Unless your IDE has specific support for it, tools in containers are completely isolated from the host system and can't be directly used from the host.

Is there a better way to achieve this that also lets me not install and configure tomcat on my local machine?

If your IDE requires a local Tomcat, then it requires a local Tomcat.  You might clarify which IDE it is, and why it needs a Tomcat installation.

Like I wrote in the original post, I'm setting up a Dynamic Web Project using Eclipse for Java EE on Linux, I need to develop a simple WebService that returns a String message. The Tomcat plugin requires a folder containing a Tomcat installation.

What it requires is a folder containing Tomcat, preferably one not installed and running as a service on your machine. Let it download one for you as part of adding a Tomcat runtime in the preferences.
